# Finding the Laurent series of a function in a given annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series, valid in $ \{z \in \Bbb C : 1 < |z| < 3 \}$ for:

$$f(z) = \frac{(9z+1)}{(z^2-9)(z^3+1)} $$

Partial fractions seems too messy which makes me think I'm missing something?

Comment: I think partial fractions is the best way to proceed here - you could try a binomial expansion but I suspect that's even more messy.

Comment: The partial fractions even end up being fairly benign: $$f(z) = \frac{(9z+1)}{(z^2-9)(z^3+1)} = \frac{1}{z^2-9} - \frac{z}{z^3+1}$$

Comment: I've clearly fallen into the trap of if there's any number crunching feeling like I've missed a trick! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By πr8's comment,
$$f(z) = \frac{(9z+1)}{(z^2-9)(z^3+1)} = \frac{1}{z^2-9} - \frac{z}{z^3+1}.$$
Moreover, for $|z|<3$,
$$\frac{1}{z^2-9}=\frac{-1/9}{1-(z/3)^2}=-\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(z/3)^{2k}=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{9^{k+1}},$$
and, for $|z|>1$,
$$\frac{z}{z^3+1}=\frac{z/z^3}{1-(-1/z^3)}=
\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1/z^3)^{k}=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{z^{3k+2}}.$$
Hence the Laurent series in $1<|z|<3$ is
$$-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{z^{3k+2}}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{9^{k+1}}.$$